# module 'tensorflow_hub' has no attribute 'KerasLayer'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

When I'm trying to retrain the model with tensorflow it shows an error:

```
**error module 'tensorflow_hub' has no attribute 'KerasLayer'**
```

The code is:

```py
print("Building model with", MODULE_HANDLE)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE, output_shape=[FV_SIZE],
    trainable=do_fine_tuning),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes,
    activation='softmax',
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
model.build((None,)+IMAGE_SIZE+(3,))
model.summary()
```

The error is like:

```
      1 print("Building model with", MODULE_HANDLE)
      2 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
----> 3     hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE, output_shape=[FV_SIZE],
      4                    trainable=do_fine_tuning),
      5     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_hub' has no attribute 'KerasLayer'
```

by using the tensorflow hub retrain the previous hub model by adding new dence fully connected layers.when run the code it show the above error.is any have idea about that.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the tensorflow version. It should be a recent nightly version.

When I use a version like 1.13.1, I see the following warning before the error, no attribute 'KerasLayer':

```
W0423 20:04:16.453974 139707130586880 __init__.py:56] Some hub symbols are not available because TensorFlow version is less than 1.14
```

After, doing `pip install "tf-nightly"`, everything works fine.

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub

For the BatchNormalizationv1 issue, you can use tf2.0 nightly which should also take care of the original issue.

```
pip install -U tf-nightly-2.0-preview
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1255

Comment: am change the tensorflow to tf-nighty but now it shows an error                     
[ValueError: Unknown layer: BatchNormalizationV1] .how can  fix it

Comment: thanks.now am install "pip install -U tf-nightly-2.0-preview".now its shows an error like  [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder']

Comment: Can you please post the complete code that I can run locally?

Comment: thankyou.by use 'pip install -U tf-nightly-2.0-preview' that problem fixed and now am  get the model h5 file.but when i load that file by using  `load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/model.h5',custom_objects={"GlorotUniform": tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform})`  . it shows an error like ** [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder']**

Answer (score 1):

hub.KerasLayer works with TF2 pre releases:

- pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview --quiet
- pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha

pre-release candidate for GPU:

- pip install -U --pre tensorflow-gpu